# How monkey tool is able to detect application crash or exceptions on Android

Tags: android

I am new to monkey tool and would like to know how exactly it works. As far as the documentation that I have gone through, monkey tool generates random events and tests the Application behavior for these random behavior. If application crashes or if any unhandled exceptions then monkey tool stops.

I would like to know how the monkey tool is able to detect the application crash or if any undhandled exceptions. Application will be a different process and monkey tool will be a different process. How is it possible by one application to know if another application crashed or has unhandled exception?

Also, how monkey tool inserts the event and how that event reaches another process (application under test)? Do we have any detailed documentation on this?

Any inputs or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it uses the platform-internal [`IActivityController`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/IActivityController.aidl) API.

Have a look at the [monkey source](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey) for details.